Security update available for Adobe Commerce - APSB24-40 popup for Magento 2.3.x
Recently, for all Magento projects, one popup suggests applying a security update patch.
I received the same popup for even Magento 2.3.x websites. However, I couldn't find any patch for it.
Can someone please advise us on where we can get this patch for the Magento 2.3.x version? And if it is not there, why do we get the notification for the same?

In my experience, if patch is not available please email adobe they will surely provide guidance on you may be they will ask you for the version upgrade.

@RanaZain Adobe doesn't provide support for the Magento 2.3.x versions. Upgrading the version is not an option soon for the specific project.

I applied the above patch today in the 2.4.5-P1

@RanaZain, I have already applied for 2.4.x. My concern is with the 2.3.x versions only.

I still have some websites under 2.3 (community) but I did not receive any notifications. Maybe it was from a 3rd party vendor ?
You can find a patch for 2.4 at the bottom of this page :  https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/known-issues-patches-attached/security-update-available-for-adobe-commerce-apsb24-40-revised-to-include-isolated-patch-for-cve-2024-34102
This patch will try edit 4 files :
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/i18n/en_US.csv b/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/i18n/en_US.csv
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/i18n/en_US.csv b/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/i18n/en_US.csv
vendor/magento/module-jwt-user-token/Model/SecretBasedJwksFactory.php b/vendor/magento/module-jwt-user-token/Model/SecretBasedJwksFactory.php
vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php

Since the module-jwt-user-token module was only introduced in 2.4.4, the patch will fail on Magento 2.3 instances.
Here's an updated version for 2.3 :
diff --git a/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/i18n/en_US.csv b/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/i18n/en_US.csv
index a491a567a37..5e8bef787d2 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/i18n/en_US.csv
+++ b/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/i18n/en_US.csv
@@ -4,3 +4,4 @@ Summary,Summary
 Menu,Menu
 Account,Account
 Settings,Settings
+"Invalid data type","Invalid data type"
diff --git a/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/i18n/en_US.csv b/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/i18n/en_US.csv
index 7bf9e0afaf0..00493cc05ba 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/i18n/en_US.csv
+++ b/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/i18n/en_US.csv
@@ -54,3 +54,4 @@ Footer,Footer
 "Update to your %store_name shipment","Update to your %store_name shipment"
 "Address Book","Address Book"
 "Account Information","Account Information"
+"Invalid data type","Invalid data type"
diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php
index 908a4e70140..cc019845b58 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php
@@ -153,6 +153,7 @@ class ServiceInputProcessor implements ServicePayloadConverterInterface
      * @return \Magento\Framework\Reflection\NameFinder
      *
      * @deprecated 100.1.0
+     * @see nothing
      */
     private function getNameFinder()
     {
@@ -261,6 +262,7 @@ class ServiceInputProcessor implements ServicePayloadConverterInterface
      * @throws \Exception
      * @throws SerializationException
      * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
+     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
      */
     protected function _createFromArray($className, $data)
     {
@@ -268,6 +270,12 @@ class ServiceInputProcessor implements ServicePayloadConverterInterface
         // convert to string directly to avoid situations when $className is object
         // which implements __toString method like \ReflectionObject
         $className = (string) $className;
+        if (is_subclass_of($className, \SimpleXMLElement::class)
+            || is_subclass_of($className, \DOMElement::class)) {
+            throw new SerializationException(
+                new Phrase('Invalid data type')
+            );
+        }
         $class = new ClassReflection($className);
         if (is_subclass_of($className, self::EXTENSION_ATTRIBUTES_TYPE)) {
             $className = substr($className, 0, -strlen('Interface'));

To execute the patch, save the content in a .patch file then execute :
git apply <name_of_the_patch>.patch

or
patch -p1 < <name_of_the_patch>.patch

Then as usual compile and deploy static content.
For information, there are PoC which can be found online. On my 2.4 websites I was able to execute successfully the attack. However the exploit did not work on my Magento 2.3 Instances.
Once I applied the patch on 2.3 and 2.4, I had the same error messge (Invalid data type).

Thanks for your information for the attack on 2.3.x stores! I'm currently drying to figure out if 2.3.x stores were vulnerable after i added the hotfix from Sansec thats checking for the dataIsURL in the JSON payload that was proven to be insufficient by writeup from Sergey
Has anyone checked if the attack works if "allow_url_fopen" is disabled?
If i try to exploit a 2.4.6-p6 store i got the exception: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

Hi, nope. It is from Magento only. Also, I am aligned with 2.4.x patches. I have already done those for all the websites with the upgraded version. My concern is with the 2.3 versions only.

@Magento Tridhya Tech
Update Magento
For Magento 2.3.x, you should apply the necessary security patches or updates. Follow these steps to update Magento:
Via Composer
Backup Your Site: Always backup your database and files before making any changes.
Check for Available Updates:
Run the following command to check for available updates:
composer update --dry-run

Update Magento:
If updates are available, apply them using:
composer update
Run Magento Upgrade Commands:
After updating via Composer, run these commands to update the database schema and data:
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean

Reindex Data:
bin/magento indexer:reindex

Manually
If you cannot use Composer, you might need to manually download and apply the patch or update files provided by Adobe. Check Magento's official documentation for detailed instructions on manual updates.

Verify the Update
After applying the update:
Test your site thoroughly to ensure everything is functioning correctly.
Check for any specific patches or instructions related to the APSB24-40 bulletin to ensure full compliance.

Security Best Practices
Regularly check for security updates and patches.
Implement additional security measures, such as firewalls and security plugins.
Monitor Magento’s official security advisories and forums for ongoing updates and issues.


Thank You!

Please stop ignoring the website guidelines. The moderators should have warned you by now about putting signatures and taglines in your posts. Also, please don't use ChatGPT to generate content for this or any other Stack Exchange site.
